# Is necessary for carbon to complete its octet?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have seen a lot of carbon compounds; all of them have a complete octet for example HCN, CO2, etc. What about more exotic ones?

Comment: It's not necessary, but highly preferable. Any carbon species without an octet is nearly always very reactive.

Comment: @orthocresol can you give some examples???

Comment: http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/164577?lang=en&region=US    So stable, you can buy it.

Comment: Which is why I absolutely had to add the qualifier "nearly always"!

Comment: I changed second sentence because it didn't making sense. Feel free to edit if you don't like it now, but be careful with grammar, spelling etc.

Comment: No. Carbenes and carbocations do not have complete octet. But that makes them very very reactive.

Answer (score 5):

There's a number of well-known persistent radicals and salts that contain carbon atoms that do not have complete octets. Examples are

- [Gomberg's (triphenylmethyl) radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triphenylmethyl_radical) and derivatives,
- [Triphenylmethyl hexafluorophosphate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triphenylmethyl_hexafluorophosphate),
- compounds that contain [tropylium cations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropylium_cation) (e.g. $\ce{[C7H7]+[BF4]-}$), or
- componds that contain the [2-norbornyl cation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-Norbornyl_cation) (e.g. $\ce{[C7H11]+[Al2Br7]- \cdot CH2Br2}$).

Answer (score 0):

No. $\ce{CH5+}$ has been observed, and $\ce{CH3}\,^\bullet$ is a common chemical reagent. ($\ce{CH5+}$ isn't stable, and $\ce{CH3}\,^\bullet$ is only 'stable' under special conditions, but never-the-less, both do exist.)

In the vast majority of organic chemistry you'll be exposed to, assuming carbon is tetravalent is an excellent starting place. The octet rule is best for the Groups 13-18 and for the 2nd period especially with the 3rd period elements usually obeying it.

Comment: In CH5+ carbon still has octet on contrary to for example CH3+

Comment: Furthermore, stable carbon-centred radicals exist (triphenylmethyl radical) as do stable carbocations (triphenylmethyl cation). And let’s not forget NHC’s.